Random pseudo-inverse matrix problem
Given a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times N_d}$, $N_d \gg n$ and $\mathrm{rank}(M) = n$, the entries of $M$ are denoted as $M_{[ij]}, i = 1,...,n, j = 1,..., N_d$ and $M_{[ij]} \in [-\textbf{m}, \textbf{m}]$ randomly (It can be regarded as the elements of the matrix are generated by sampling from $[-\textbf{m}, \textbf{m}]$, and the matrix $M$ consists of the positive elements and the negative elements and zero. Practically the matrix can be generated using command 2 * m * rand(n, Nd) - m in MATLAB). Can it be proved that the sum of the row of matrix $M^{\dagger}M$ i.e. $\sum^{N_d}_{j=1} M^{\dagger}M_{[i, j]} < 1$ for $i = 1, ..., N_d$ with probability 1? $M^{\dagger}$ refers to the Moore-Penrose inverse of $M$.
I have verified a lot of test examples such that $\sum^{N_d}_{j=1} M^{\dagger}M_{[i, j]} < 1$ holds.

oops, I mistook $\dagger$ for conjugate, but it is pseudo-inverse

You mean the sum of values in any row of your product matrix is $< 1$. Writing $\sum^{N_d}{j=1} (M^{\dagger}M){[i, j]} < 1$ would make it clearer. Now what does $\sum^{N_d}{i=1} (M^{\dagger}M){[i, :]} < 1$ mean? A sum of row vectors compared to the scalar $1$?

@Claude Sorry for my mistake, that was a typo and I've re-edited the question, the former is what I was trying to say.

@Dima I apologize for the lack of explanation of the notations, I've re-edited the question.
